# Strange behavior of Session variable in web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

Please read my question it is not related to how to access webmethod or how to use session.'

I am facing one issue and did not get it.

I have one sessioninfo class that contains all session related info in that.
When I am using it in Page_load() it is working fine.but when I will try to access it in webmethod it show me error like this : "SessionInfo.UserId error CS0103: The name 'SessionInfo' does not exist in the current context"

here is my code
SessionInfo Class

```
namespace Abc.Common
{
      public class SessionInfo
      {
          public static decimal UserID
          {
             get
             {
                 try
                 {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] != null)
                       return Convert.ToDecimal(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]);
                    return 0;
                 }
                 catch (Exception)
                 {
                    return 0;
                 }
             }
             set
             {
                 HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] = value;
             }
         }
         ...
         ...
      }
  }
```

//backend code of asp.net (.aspx.cs)

```
using Abc.common;
....
```

Code in Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SessionInfo.UserID == 0)    //here its working fine
    {
        Response.Redirect(Page.ResolveUrl("~/Default.aspx?errormsg=Your Session Is Expired."));
    }
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Code of Webmethod

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static DataTable ValidateUploadedFiles()
{
     //if (Abc.Common.SessionInfo.UserID == 0)    //its working fine
     if (SessionInfo.UserID == 0)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

when I used sessioninfo variable directly its giving me error(already namespace is included in using statement)

```
SessionInfo.UserID  //this want work.
```

when I will used its with namespace with class its working fine.

```
Abc.Common.SessionInfo.UserID  //this is working fine.
```

Answer (score 2):

From your description I'm assuming that you are missing "using" statement at the top of your file.
Just add "using Abc.Common;" in first line of your file and it should work fine.
Oh. And it has nothing to do with it being webmethod. It's just how namespaces work.

Comment: I have mention that I have used using statement. but its strange issue.